# JndiLookupFailureException when spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Please see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284947/springboot-jndi-datasource-throws-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-t)  where I added data source information in JNDI of embedded tomcat.

Now I wish to suppress database metadata initialization sql scripts so I add property , `spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false` in `application.properties`, please [see this.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database)

When I add this property, I start getting below exception. If I remove this property, all works well.

Not sure what I am missing.

```
ERROR - 2016-09-05 09:44:46.358; org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep; Encountered an error executing step step1 in job RCMatcher
org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/RCMatcherDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JdbcPagingItemReader.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader.read(SynchronizedItemStreamReader.java:55)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/RCMatcherDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:135)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: That exception is complaining when the reader is started and has nothing to do with initialization....

Comment: but I see error gone when I remove , `spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false` from `application.properties`. My reader code is as [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219899/spring-batch-how-to-complete-a-job-when-the-jdbcpagingitemreader-returns-no-da). When I remove this property, I do see attempt to execute sql script for meta tables but that should all be the change due to this property. I can share more code if needed.